# Transition from sentence to one word

Tags: css, css-transitions

What I am trying to achieve is to animate an element width few words in the way that hovered word leaves in the center of the element and the rest smoothly goes out of the bounds. I would also keep it as clear as possible in HTML and not to use fixed pixel amount of margins/widths to position elements.

The very lousy sketch of what I have on my mind is here:

```css
* {
  transition: all 1.5s;
}

div {
  min-width: 150px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  background: orange;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div:hover {
  background: white;
  word-spacing: 300px;
}

a:hover::after,
a:hover::before {
  content: ' ';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="afirst" href="">First</a> & <a class="asecond" href="">Second</a>
</div>
```

Each word on hover should go to center (possibly not with those 'jumps' visible now when other words disapear). Do you have any ideas? I'm pretty sure that the way I try to follow with word-spacing is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that when increasing word spacing the text goes to new line and create this jump thing. So you may add `white-space: nowrap` and you can also use padding-left to push text and make it in the center :

```css
div {
  min-width: 150px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  background: orange;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div:hover {
  word-spacing: 80px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="afirst" href="">First</a> & <a class="asecond" href="">Second</a>
</div>
```

Actually the word spacing is applied to the div so you cannot apply hover on word. It's also easier to apply this technique on the first word as the second one will be hide with overflow, but am not sure how you can do the same with the second word with the use of word-spacing.

---

Here is another idea on how you can do without word-spacing. I used some padding animation and also pseudo element to hide the first word when hovering the second one.

```css
div {
  min-width: 150px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  background: orange;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.afirst,
.asecond {
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.afirst:hover {
  padding: 0 44%;
  background: white;
}
.asecond:hover {
  padding: 0 50% 0 0;
  background: white;
}
.asecond:hover::before {
  content:" ";
  position:absolute;
  left:-50%;
  width:50%;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:99;
  background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="afirst" href="">First</a> & <a class="asecond" href="">Second</a>
</div>
```

I think you can generalize this solution by using **:before** element in the left and **:after** element in the right to hide everything else.

Here is an example with multiple word (but not giving center alignement correctly, still need improvement) :

```css
div {
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  background: orange;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.word {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.word:hover {
  background: white;
  padding: 0 40%;
}

.word:hover::before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  background: #fff;
}

.word:hover::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  right: -50%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="word" href="">First</a> &
  <a class="word" href="">Second</a> &
  <a class="word" href="">third</a> &
  <a class="word" href="">Fourth</a>
</div>
```

Another solution with perfect centering but less animation for the other words :

```css
div {
  position:relative;
  height: 25px;
  width:500px;
  margin:0 auto;
  line-height: 25px;
  background: orange;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.word {
  position: relative;
  z-index:9;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.word:hover {
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  text-align:center;
  background: white;
  z-index:99;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="word" href="">First</a> &
  <a class="word" href="">Second</a> &
  <a class="word" href="">third</a> &
  <a class="word" href="">Fourth</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's the nice improvement. But still far from the solution, I think. As you stated -- the second word (or more) will be the challenge.

Comment: @friedman, check my update ;) i made a try for the second word :)

Comment: That looks really promising! Few more details to polish (especially to keep it in the center of the div) and there we go! :D

Comment: @friedman i also added a more generic solution with multiple words ;) it can be a good start but need to be improved

Answer (score 1):

This version uses **Flex Box**, accommodates **multiple items**, and **does not use fixed widths**.

The trouble I kept having playing around with this was centering items without using fixed widths. Especially those that were later in line and trying to push items to the left.

**Solution**: flex box `order`.

You can set the order of flex items numerically, so simply setting it to -1 on hover puts the hovered item first in the list so you eliminate the issue of flexing items leftward.

The animation may not be as fluid as you're looking for because you can only transition order by integer.  So it's immediately set along with the width, and then the other properties transition.

```css
div.outer {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 30px;
  background: orange;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}

div.inner {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 30px;
  width: 50vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: transparent;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

span {
   order: 1;
   padding: 0 3px;
   flex-shrink:1;
}

a {
  z-index: 0;
  order: 1;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  transition: background .5s, flex-grow .25s, flex-shrink .25s;
 }

a:hover {
  z-index: 10;
  width: 50vw;
  order: -1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <a href="">First</a>
    <span>&amp;</span>
    <a href="">Second</a>
    <span>&amp;</span>
    <a href="">Third</a>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Robert. I will work on combining your approach with @Temani's as both have great solutions but need polishing :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't perfect, but I think it comes pretty close to achieving what you were looking for. Using a little bit of jQuery was necessary for math (but not the animations themselves).

Hope this gets you further!

```js
function reset() {
  // reset all spans
  $('.animate span').css('transform', '');
  $('.animate span.active').removeClass('active');
}

$('.animate').on('mouseover', 'span:not(.active)', function() {
  reset();

  // set current hovered word to active
  $(this).addClass('active');

  // slide over previous/next words
  $(this).prevAll().css('transform', 'translateX(-100vw)');
  $(this).nextAll().css('transform', 'translateX(100vw)');

  // determine offset for center of hovered word
  var center = (window.innerWidth / 2) - ($(this).offset().left + ($(this).width() / 2));
  // slide current word to center
  $(this).css('transform', 'translateX(' + center + 'px)');
});

// when leaving animate section, reset
$('.animate').mouseleave(reset);
```

```css
.animate {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .5s background-color, .5s color;
}

.animate:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: orange;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 3s transform;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="animate">
  <span><a href="#">First</a></span> <span>&amp;</span> <span><a href="#">Second</a></span> <span>&amp;</span> <span><a href="#">Third</a></span> <span>and</span> <span><a href="#">Fourth</a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: But the question is not tagged with jQuery

Comment: @TemaniAfif Again, jQuery isn't being used for the animation aspect - that's all CSS3.  The styles I'm applying could just as well be done (less concisely) with vanilla JS. I don't see a problem with using a common library to come up with a solution just because the question doesn't have it tagged.

Comment: yes, but **in my opinion** the use of jQuery or JS make the problem trivial (since you can easily manipulate all the elements). I think the OP wants to have a pure CSS solution and that's why he didn't tag it with Jquery or JS. Am not complaining about your solution as it's a good one. (this is simply my opinion )